# 0's in the beginning are being skipped & I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: python, binary

The output value is not including the 0's in the beginning, can someone help me fix the problem?

```
def bitwiseOR(P, Q):
    return bin(P | Q)

bitwiseOR(0b01010111, 0b00111000)
```

```
OUTPUT: '0b1111111'
```

Comment: Leading zeros are a display concept, they don't get translated to the numeric value.  For display purposes leading zeros are generally dropped because A) there's no way to know how many there were originally and B) they're redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading zeroes are just for representation, so you can utilize [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to display them as you wish:

Format string:

1. `#` Includes `0b` prefix
2. `0{length}` Pad leading zeroes so total length is `length`

```
def bitwiseOR(P, Q, length=10):
    return format(P | Q, f'#0{length}b')

x = bitwiseOR(0b01010111, 0b00111000)
# 0b01111111
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! What about the f? what does that mean exactly?

Comment: That means that we can format variables onto the string, that's called [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)

Answer (score 0):

Leading zeros are a property of the string you produce, not the number. So, for example, if you're looking for a way to make the following two calls produce different results, that's not possible:<sup>1</sup>

```
bitwiseOR(0b01010111, 0b00111000)
bitwiseOR( 0b1010111,   0b111000)
```

However, if you can provide the number of digits separately, then you can do this using [the `format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format). It accepts a second argument which lets you customize how the number is printed out using [the format spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). Based on that spec, you can print a number padded with zeros to a given width like this:

```
>>> format(127, '#010b')
'0b01111111'
```

Here the code consists of four pieces:

- `#` means apply the `0b` prefix at the beginning
- `0` means pad with leading zeros
- `10` means the total length of the resulting string should be at least 10 characters
- `b` means to print the number in binary

You can tweak the format code to produce your desired string length, or even take the length from a variable.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well... technically there is a way to make Python re-read its own source code and possibly produce different results that way, but that's not useful in any real program, it's only useful if you want to learn something about how the Python interpreter works.